# Maximum call stack size exceeded when using server prefetch for algolia

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, algolia

Hello i have aloglia in nuxt and want server side rendering.

I'm writing in typescript nuxt, so thats why i type convert my "this" to make instantsearch work.

When I use the serverPrefetch method like this:

```
 serverPrefetch() {
    return (this as any).instantsearch.findResultsState(this).then((algoliaState: any) => {
      this.$ssrContext.nuxt.algoliaState = algoliaState;
      console.log(this.$ssrContext.nuxt.algoliaState);
    });
  },
```

I get this error:
[image: image of the error i get in browser]

And in terminal I get this:

[image: image of terminal]

Anyone else who had this issute with nuxt algolia?.

Algolia works fine when i remove the serverPrefetch method but then is nothing serverside rendered.

Comment: The Algolia X Nuxt rely on `asyncData` not `serverPrefetch`. You have a dedicated guide about the integration on the [Algolia documentation](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/going-further/server-side-rendering/vue/#with-nuxt). Does it help? Keep in mind that the plugins leak by default. You can take a look a this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/algolia/vue-instantsearch/issues/685) for more information.

Comment: if you see their documentation after the upgrade to v3 in nuxt they have changed the asyncData to serverprefetch the link is here: https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/going-further/server-side-rendering/vue/

Comment: but thanks for the memory leak problem @SamuelVaillant

Comment: Hoops my bad... Are you able to setup a quick example in CodeSandbox?

Comment: Yea, but i can also send you a hastebin with the code i got? :) aloglia already have a sandbox with algolia nuxt. @SamuelVaillant

Comment: https://hastebin.com/ogipofarug.js @SamuelVaillant

Comment: Yes but I have to mock your import etc... It's kinda cumbersome to build. With a reproducible example at least I can start straight with the issue. Your setup I think is different from the example in the repo otherwise you wouldn't have an issue.

Comment: @SamuelVaillant can i ask you to send a mail on ab@lait.dk? what repo?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that I was using fetch AND prefetch in a component, this triggers this issue, just moved my fetch functionality to prefetch and the algolia now work.